# Cannot start Neo4j Server after Spatial data load

Tags: java, neo4j

I've been trying to use the Neo4j Spatial plugin with data loaded via Java. I have added the plugin, and when I start an empty database this is confirmed by the following GET request to the server.

```
{
    "extensions": {
        "SpatialPlugin": {
            "addSimplePointLayer": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addSimplePointLayer",
            "findClosestGeometries": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findClosestGeometries",
            "addNodesToLayer": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodesToLayer",
            "addGeometryWKTToLayer": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addGeometryWKTToLayer",
            "findGeometriesWithinDistance": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance",
            "addEditableLayer": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addEditableLayer",
            "addCQLDynamicLayer": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addCQLDynamicLayer",
            "addNodeToLayer": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer",
            "getLayer": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/getLayer",
            "findGeometriesInBBox": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesInBBox",
            "updateGeometryFromWKT": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/updateGeometryFromWKT"
        }
    },
    "node": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
    "node_index": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
    "relationship_index": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
    "extensions_info": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
    "relationship_types": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
    "batch": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
    "cypher": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
    "indexes": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index",
    "constraints": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint",
    "transaction": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction",
    "node_labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/labels",
    "neo4j_version": "2.3.2"
}
```

However, when I stop the server, load my spatial data via Java with a `SpatialIndexProvider.SIMPLE_WKT_CONFIG` index, then adding it with:

```
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> index = db.index().forNodes("location", SpatialIndexProvider.SIMPLE_WKT_CONFIG);

            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] columns = line.split(",");
                Node node = db.createNode();
                node.setProperty("wkt", String.format("POINT(%s %s)", columns[4], columns[3]));
                node.setProperty("name", columns[0]);
                index.add(node, "dummy", "value");
            }

            tx.success();
        }
```

After a restart, I get the error:

```
2016-02-23 13:44:36.747+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.KernelHealth] setting TM not OK. Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform necessary action (tx recovery/restart) No index provider 'spatial' found. Maybe the intended provider (or one more of its dependencies) aren't on the classpath or it failed to load.
```

in `Messages.log` inside the graph.db. Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

I'm on windows 8, Neo4j 2.3.2, Java 8 and neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you unzip the full spatial zip into the plugins directory?

Otherwise some classes that spatial needs can't be found.

Comment: Ahh yes, I had only copied the neo4j-spatial-0.15-neo4j-2.3.0.jar into the plugins folder (didn't follow the docs correctly). Many thanks